# Is it possible to "change the focal plane" of a 2d image?

Tags: optics

Can we apply some type of transformation to 2D image in such a way that when a person looks at it directly (i.e. focuses on the paper or the computer screen which displays the image), it is blurry; however, when the observer focuses on a point far away, behind the screen, the content of the image becomes clear?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about an image that could be presented on a printed page, or on a standard LCD display, where the light from any one point is emitted in all directions. The answer is (unfortunately) no. When your eye is properly focused on an image, all the light which ends up at a specific point on your retina comes from a specific point on the image. There's no way for the image to be designed otherwise; that's the way lenses work.

If you adjust your lens such that the focus is behind the actual image plane, then (due to the size of your pupil) light that arrives at a single point on your retina will come from an area on the image. This inevitably blurs the image by acting as a 2D low-pass filter, discarding fine spatial features (if any) but preserving broad features. Adjacent points on your retina collect light from overlapping areas on the image, which makes it impossible to build a high-contrast, in-focus image.

If, however, you had some sort of system which could fully control the direction of the emitted light, then the answer is (in theory) yes. All you'd have to do is to have your image emit light in the directions and locations that would have been emitted by a standard image at the user's focal point. That's what holograms do; they use interference to generate a specific pattern of light in specific directions, causing the appearance of an object in space (generally a 3D object, but they could create a 2D image plane, but that would be far less impressive).